# Databricks shows REDACTED on a hardcoded value

Tags: pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I am using Azure Databricks to take the environment value from the Azure Key Vault which has the value `intg`.

```
env = dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "myscrope", key = "environment")
```

When I print this, it shows as `[REDACTED]`, which is expected.

Now I declare another variable as below.

```
prm = 'myintgterritoy'
```

When I print this, it is showing as `my[REDACTED]territoy` as the `intg` keyword is in this. I am not expecting this behaviour as this is entirely a different variable. How can I get the value as `myintgterritoy`?

I tried an approach where I can put the actual value with a whitespace using the below code to a new variable.

```
new_prm = ''
for char in prm:
  new_prm += char + ' '
```

But when I replace space with empty string, it is giving the result back as `my[REDACTED]territoy`.

```
new_prm.replace(' ','')
```

I am expecting the output as `myintgterritoy`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible, Databricks just scans entire output for occurences of secret values and replaces them with "[REDACTED]".

It is helpless if you transform the value. For example, like you tried already, you could insert spaces between characters and that would reveal the value. You can use a trick with an invisible character - for example Unicode [invisible separator](https://unicode-explorer.com/c/2063), which is encoded as `0xE281A3` in UTF-8.

```
invisible_sep = bytes.fromhex("E281A3").decode("utf-8")
secret = dbutils.secrets.get("myscrope", "environment")
plaintextSecret = secret.replace("", invisible_sep)
print(secret)  # would print "[REDACTED]"
print(plaintextSecret)  # would print "intg"
```

Note that what looks like "intg" in reality is "<sep>i<sep>n<sep>t<sep>g<sep>" - so the separator is still there, just invisible, and will remain if you eg. copy-paste the value.

Better, use secret scope for what really is a secret and for other variables pick other tools like Azure App Configuration or Consul KV or maybe just a config file.

Comment: Thanks Kombajn for the help. I am hoping Databricks may resolve this limitation in the future.